# How to tell if a child of wx.Panel was placed above or unde another child (wxpython)?

Tags: python, graphics, wxpython, wxwidgets, overlap

I have a wx.Panel with multiple children in it.

How do i tell, when placing another child, if it's not stepping on an already placed child?

(i mean i can think of the solution where I itterate through the list of children, get all their positions and sizes and do the math.... but I want to know if there isn't already an easier solution)

[EDIT]: I need to have multiple panels with outlines on a parent panel, and lines connecting the child panels.  The idea is to be able to tell if a line is not crossing another panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components that are windows (wx.Panel, wx.StaticLine etc) have a method `.getRect` that returns a wx.Rect.

The [wx.Rect](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Rect-class.html) has a method `.Intersects(self, otherRect)` which returns true if the 2 elements overlap.

There's also a [wx.Rect2D](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Rect2D-class.html) which has some aditional functionality - Interpolating, getting the intersection AND union, etc.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to avoid the issue by using sizers to place the children.  Much, much easier.

I see from your edit that you are not concerned about overlapping widgets, as the title of your question indicates, but whether a line overlaps a widget.

My suggestion for this, different, problem is to look into using GraphViz ( http://www.graphviz.org/ ) which will calculate effective layouts that minimize overlaps and often eliminate them entirely.  For same examples of what can be achieved, take a look at http://ravenspoint.com/maps.html

Comment: does indeed help with my actual problem.